# Composition of objects vs functions: Should I use one method interfaces or delegates?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, architecture, f#

C# is a multi paradigm language. By nesting interfaces and classes one can get a composition of **objects**. This way a certain problem can be broken down to a number of simple ones giving each component its own piece of the puzzle to solve. The same trick can be done in a slightly different manner, one can make a composition of **functions** each of which is responsible of solving its own little task while all combined and interconnected they give the answer to the main problem.

Following SOLID principles I found myself in a situation where 95% of my interfaces carry just one method  named do-something and the name of the interface is something-doer. The class that implements such interfaces is DI'ed with the a few components required to fulfill whatever that method is supposed to do.  Such approach is basically making a closure over a function by hands. If so, why wouldn't I just go with delegates that do it naturally and for free (no typing necessary)? If I go all the way converting single method interfaces to delegates I will eliminate 95% of them from my code making it look like written in functional language. But this seems like a right thing to do unless there is some bold reason to stick with interfaces. Is there?

UPDATE:

@Fendy, Let me argue a bit. You have said

***"You cannot control the delegate logic from BLL***". Well, delegates can be defined anywhere not necessarily in callers. One can perfectly do this:

```
public namespace Bbl
{
    public static class TestableUtils {
        public static Func<A, B> CreateA2B() {
            Func<A, B> a2b = a => new B(a);
            return a2b;
        }
        public static Func<B, C> CreateB2C() {
            Func<B, C> b2c = b => new C(b);
            return b2c;
        }
        public static Func<A, C> CreateA2C(Func<A, B> a2b, Func<B, C> b2c)
        {
            Func<A, C> a2c = a => b2c(a2b(a));
            return a2c;
        }
    }
}

public namespace Caller
{
    using Bbl;
    public class Demo()
    {
        public void RunMe()
        {
            var a = new A();
            var a2b = TestableUtils.CreateA2B();
            var b2c = TestableUtils.CreateB2C();
            var a2c = TestableUtils.CreateA2C(a2b, b2c);
            var c = a2c(a);
        }
    }
}
```

***"If not careful, code duplication everywhere"***, That's true, be lazy and careful, so you don't do the same work more than once. The same problem can easily happen with classes. So delegates are no different.

***"If constructor injected and using mutable entity, it can lead to stateful interface"*** I am sorry I don't see a problem with your example. I mean it does exactly what it programmed for. If you mutate entities this is what you would expect, wouldn't you? You can be safe just by preventing Name from being set outside of the constructor. If you do that then the situation from your example won't be possible.

Basically out of 4 points that you have laid out none has anything to do with having more problems using delegates compared to doing the same with interfaces/classes. Or I just didn't get it.

Comment: May I know, whether do you basically based from OOP following SOLID principle, or based from functional programming, in which it has different based design with OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that the answer is ***BIG FAT NO***, one cannot use delegates instead of single method interfaces for 2 fundamental reasons:

1. C# doesn't support recursive anonymous functions.
2. There are not type aliases in C#, so the signatures of functions quickly become hideous and unmanageable.

Bad luck.

Comment: This is a late comment, but wanted to point out to any readers out there that C# has what's called a [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) which somewhat solves the issue in point 2. Basically, you can do `using MyCustomAction = System.Action<int, int, float>;`. However, this only applies to the file you're working in.

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is, pretty much, a one method interface.

A closure is creating a new nested class, behind the scenes, it's just doing a lot of the related boilerplate for you to make the code cleaner.

In short, delegates and lambdas/closures were *created* to solve the problem that interfaces and nested classes are used for in languages without those features.  You are not abusing these features to use them in this context.

That said, there isn't anything wrong with using classes/interfaces if you prefer it; it's just a bit more explicit.  It's also more powerful, and is generally useful if the operation you're representing is more complex then a small class with a single method, so it's not like delegates and lambdas replaces interfaces entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, as in the most application design applies, is "**it depends**".

As you already know, delegates are defined in the caller. It means that:

1. You cannot control the delegate logic from BLL. This is also means `NO UNIT TEST` for the function
2. If not careful, code duplication everywhere
3. Registering the delegate at composition root / constructor injection? [read this first](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/11/di-and-events-composition)
4. If constructor injected and using mutable entity, it can lead to stateful interface

**Example for point no.4:**

Below example only showing how constructor injected delegate with mutable entity can lead to stateful implementation.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EvilDeleg
{
    public EvilDeleg(Action<Employee> act)
    {
        this.act = act;
    }
    Action<Employee> act;
    public void DoSomething(Employee emp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); // resulting in "First"
        emp.Name = " Evil";
        act(emp);
        Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); // resulting in " Evil Second"
    }
}

public class TestStatefulInterface
{
    public void ConsumeEvilDeleg()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        EvilDeleg deleg = new EvilDeleg(k => k.Name = k.Name + " Second");
        emp.Name = "First";

        deleg.DoSomething(emp);
        Console.WriteLine(emp.Name); // resulting in " Evil Second"
    }   
}
```

**So, when is it appropriate for using the delegate over one-method interface?**

My 2 cents:

1. The code does not have business-related code. You want to control the business aspect of your system, and having it anonymous to be controlled can be a pain
2. The code most likely have UI / DB - specific implementation. Such as conversion from `DataTable` to `Entity`, or `Entity` to UI `ViewModel`
3. It is trivial and do not need unit test
4. It is being injected in the method, not constructor, otherwise do not use mutable structure as input, or just use non-parameter delegate

Additionaly, [Mark Seeman](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/28/DelegatesAreAnonymousInterfaces/) states in his blog that said:

> only works as long as you only need to abstract a single method. As
>   soon as your abstraction needs a second method, you will need to
>   introduce a proper interface or, preferably, an abstract base class.